# Event in worksheet are not optimized

Tags: ws

I want to write an event for this worksheet that when I change the value in column I and column M specifically the white lines,
the data in the purple and yellow lines from column I to column N will automatically sum up, column N = column I - column M ; column J = Column G - column I.
The code I wrote seems a bit messy and not correct. When unfortunately I click on column I purple or yellow line (eg I3, I5)
then my code gives an error, and when I delete the line between line 4 and line 26, an error also occurs

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim i As Integer, a As Integer, b As Integer, d As Integer, x As Integer
Dim lr_b1 As Integer, c As Range, j As Integer, y As Integer, w As Long, z As Long

lr_b1 = Range("F" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    
    If Target.CountLarge > 1 Then Exit Sub

    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("I4:I" & lr_b1)) Is Nothing And Target.Column = 9 Then
    
    If Target.Offset(0, -2) = "" And Target.Offset(0, -8) = "" Then
    
        x = Target.Row
    
    End If

    End If
    
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("M4:M" & lr_b1)) Is Nothing And Target.Column = 13 Then
    
    If Target.Offset(0, -2) = "" And Target.Offset(0, -8) = "" Then
    
        'Target.Offset(0, 1) = Target.Offset(0, -4) - Target.Value
        
        x = Target.Row
        
    End If
    
    ElseIf Target.Column <> 9 And Target.Column <> 13 Then Exit Sub
    
    End If
    
        a = x

        Do Until a < x
            
            For i = a To 3 Step -1
                
                If Range("A" & i).Value <> "" And Range("F" & i).Value <> "" Then
                    
                b = i
                
                Exit Do
                    
                End If
                
                Next
               
        a = a - 1
        Loop
        
        a = x
        Do Until a >= lr_b1
            
            For i = a To lr_b1
                
                If Range("A" & i).Value <> "" And Range("F" & i).Value <> "" Then
                    
                d = i
                    
                Exit Do
                    
                End If
                
                Next
                
        a = a + 1
            
        Loop
       
        a = x

        Do Until a < x
            
            For i = a To 3 Step -1
                
                If Left(Range("F" & i).Value, 4) Like "*-*" Or i = lr_b1 Then
                    
                j = i
                
                Exit Do
                    
                End If
                
                Next
               
        a = a - 1
        Loop
       
        a = x
        Do Until a >= lr_b1
            
            For i = a To lr_b1
                
                If Left(Range("F" & i).Value, 4) Like "*-*" Or i = lr_b1 Then
                    
                y = i
                    
                Exit Do
                    
                End If
                
                Next
                
        a = a + 1
            
        Loop
        
   
Application.EnableEvents = False

Cells(x, 14) = Cells(x, 9) - Cells(x, 13)
Cells(b, 9) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(Range(Cells(b + 1, 9), Cells(d - 1, 9)))
Cells(b, 10) = Cells(b, 7) - Cells(b, 9)

Cells(b, 13) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(Range(Cells(b + 1, 13), Cells(d - 1, 13)))
Cells(b, 14) = Cells(b, 9) - Cells(b, 13)
'End If
'top

z = 0
w = 0
For i = j + 1 To y - 1
    If Cells(i, 1) <> "" And Cells(i, 6) <> "" Then
    'Stop
    w = w + Cells(i, 9).Value
    z = z + Cells(i, 13).Value
    End If
Next i
'Stop
Cells(j, 9) = w
Cells(j, 10) = Cells(j, 7) - Cells(j, 9)

Cells(j, 13) = z
Cells(j, 14) = Cells(j, 9) - Cells(j, 13)

Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```